# Extract time only from a Datetime Moment.js object

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have the Moment.js date object `marketStartTime` below:

[image: moment.js date object]

I want to extract the time (hours, seconds and am/pm) from the above object and keep it as a moment object (not just a string).

I figured out an ugly way to do this below:

```
moment(moment(marketStartTime, TIME_FORMAT).format(TIME_FORMAT), TIME_FORMAT)
```

I first convert the moment to a time string and then convert the time string back to a moment.

Is there anyway t just extract the time from the moment object and keep it as a moment object?

Comment: `moment.duration`, is not useful to your problem?

Comment: @hosar I don't need a time range, I just need one time.  I don't see how moment.duration can help me here, but if you have further insight into this, that would be great!

Comment: @Vtron89 what do you mean with _extract the time (hours, seconds and am/pm) from the above object and keep it as a moment object (not just a string)_? Note that moment objects (like native JS Date) always represent both time and date (defaults to today).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a duration based on the start of the date
I've used it like this:

```
        var from = (value.clone()).startOf('d');           
        this.innerValue = m.duration({ from: from, to: value });
```

remember to use moment version >2 (I'm using 2.17.1). As of version 2.1 they have improved support for durations see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
moment().format("h:mm:ss a")
```

I'm finding it for the most stright forward way. 
Also, you can check the formats you can use [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/):